# Is it possible to put numbers on top of a matplot histogram?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, statistics, histogram

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

randomnums = np.random.normal(loc=9,scale=6, size=400).astype(int)+15
```

Output:

```
array([25, 22, 19, 26, 24,  9, 19, 32, 30, 25, 29, 17, 21, 14, 17, 27, 27,
       28, 17, 17, 20, 21, 16, 28, 20, 24, 15, 20, 20, 13, 33, 21, 30, 27,
        8, 22, 24, 25, 23, 13, 24, 20, 16, 32, 15, 26, 34, 16, 21, 21, 28,
       22, 23, 18, 20, 22, 23, 22, 23, 26, 22, 25, 19, 29, 14, 27, 21, 23,
       24, 19, 25, 15, 22, 23, 19, 19, 23, 21, 22, 17, 25, 15, 24, 25, 23 ...
```

```
h = sorted(randomnums)
plt.hist(h,density=False)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Histogram]

From my research I found only how to plot numbers on top of a bar chart, but what I want is to plot on top of a histogram chart. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean `plt.gca().xaxis.tick_top()`? This sets the tick marks and labels at the top.  By the way, there is no need to sort the values before calling `hist`.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28931750/10197418) is helpful?

Comment: JohanC, What I meant is the number on top of the bar, not place the x axis on top. BTW thank your for pointing out that I don't need to sort the values.

Comment: MrFuppes, thanks for you comment, like this, but with plt.hist()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An adapted version of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28931750/10197418) I linked in the comments of the question. Thanks a lot for the suggestions in the comments below this post!

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

h = np.random.normal(loc=9,scale=6, size=400).astype(int)+15

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 10))
ax.hist(h, density=False)

for rect in ax.patches:
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.annotate(f'{int(height)}', xy=(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2, height), 
                xytext=(0, 5), textcoords='offset points', ha='center', va='bottom')
```

...gives e.g.
[image]

See also: [matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-annotate).

Comment: Just use `f'{int(height)}'` instead of the label to show the exact value.

Comment: The call to `ax.hist(...)` returns a tuple whose first element is an array containing the number of elements per bin. This can be used as labels: `labels, _, _ = ax.hist(h, density=False)` instead of the generic `label i`.

Comment: To not have the position depend too much on the scale of the y-axis, you could just use `height` without adding 1, but adding a newline to the text. As in `ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2, height, f'{int(height)}\n', ha='center', va='bottom')`

Comment: @ConnerM.: that's really cool, thanks for the hint! Also JohanC! will make an edit...

Comment: @JohanC: thanks for the newline suggestion. In any case, an ugliness can occur if a bar goes up to y max. - the label is then outside the frame. Specifying ylim could prevent this.

Comment: Still bettter would be to use `ax.annotate` instead of `ax.text`. Then you can specify the offset as a visual distance. E.g. `ax.annotate(f'{int(height)}', xy=(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2, height), xytext=(0, 5),  textcoords='offset points', ha='center', va='bottom')`

Comment: @JohanC: I feel I'm learning more than the guy who has asked the question ;-) Thanks again!

Comment: Why use plt.subplots()?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Is it possible to detail more the x axis? Like having marks '5,7.5,10,12.5,15....42.5,45' ? I think I found how to: "plt.xticks(np.arange(min(h),max(h)+1,2))"